# Maven zip Assembly, include subdirectory content

Tags: java, regex, file, maven, ant

I have the following assembly descriptor for a maven script:

```
<filesets>

   <fileSet>
      <directory>./target/dependency/local/java</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>*/*</include>
      </includes>
      <outputDirectory>thirdparty/java</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>

</filesets>
```

My intention is to include in my zip assembly all the content files of the subdirectory under the path target/dependency/local/java but not the subdirectory it self.
The full path i want to include is: target/dependency/local/java/7.0.51
The out path should be:  thirdparty/java

I tried regexp as follow:

```
<directory>%regex[./target/dependency/local/java/**/*.*]</directory>
```

but it didn't work.
Please Help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I'm leaving this for lost souls who found this unanswered question.

You need to change the include to **/* to include everything in the specified directory. That is the only thing you need to change.

Comment: Thank you, better late than never :)

Comment: You can also simply not define `<includes>` at all in this case.